# find original video if you have a short clip from it

Tags: video

I while back I wrote a paper with simulations, and to illustrate some points, I made a few cuts from chosen from long videos of the simulation running. Unfortunately, I absolutely forgot to record which part of which video I used. Since I don't really feel like going through all of them, I am looking for way to find the original videos based on the short clips I made from them. So the situtation is this: I have 100 videos and four short clips that I made by cutting four continous parts from one of the 100 longer videos (probably from like 2-3 of the 100 was used). Is there a tool that could find which clip matches to which video?

(To make matters worse, the originals are avis and the clips were exported from Openshot as mp4, but I guess lets focus on one issue at a time :D)